# Transfer file from remote server to local in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, download, remote-server

I am working with an ASP.NET website that is deployed on a remote server using IIS. When a user logs on to access the site, they have an option to download a file. However, the file gets saved to the remote server rather than the user's local computer.

Is there a way to transfer/copy the file that is saved on the remote server to the user's own local computer? Or some way that I can indicate that the file needs to be saved to the local computer instead of the remote server?

Below is the code I am using to download the files (csv and mat). The mat file download is more complicated than a typical file download, and requires a NuGet package extension. So there is not much flexibility in how the file is create and downloaded, which is why I think it may be simpler to transfer the file from the server to the local computer after everything is saved.

```
//matCheck and csvCheck are booleans that allow the user to pick one or both of the file formats to download as.
if (matCheck == true)
            {

//MLArray and MatFileWriter are part of the nuget extension I mentioned above

                List<MLArray> mlList = new List<MLArray>();
                mlList.Add(structure);
                new MatFileWriter(new FileStream(downloadsPath +  FN + ".mat", FileMode.Create), mlList, false);
               
            }
            if (csvCheck == true)
            {
//sb is the variable created in earlier code storing the csv data to download
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(downloadsPath + FN + ".csv", sb.ToString());

                var response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
                response.BufferOutput = true;
                response.Clear();
                response.ClearHeaders();
                response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
                response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" +  FN + ".csv");
                response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                response.Write(sb.ToString());
                response.End();
                


            }
```

Comment: What is downloadsPath?  The file should be saved in the client browser code after the response is received.

Comment: downloadsPath is a string storing the C:/Users/UserName/Downloads/ path for the logged in user.

Comment: The why are you adding "\\" to the path?

Comment: No, a web application can't decide where it will write its file, otherwise a malicous site could overwrite important files on a visitor's computer. Write the data to the response, so the client will download it in a downloads folder. Also, one response can contain one file, so if you want to return multiple, you should zip them.